# Grails session rendering Operations

Tags: spring, grails

I have just migrated from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.3.9, same code worked fine but i now get the following error:

```
Error |
2015-01-20 22:04:28,577 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR domain.SimpleMailService  - Unable to send email to
Message: Error executing tag <r:img>: You cannot use the session in non-request rendering operations
Line | Method
->>  107 | throwRootCause                        in /grails-app/views/mail/sendAccountResetMail.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot use the session in non-request rendering operations
->>   -2 | newInstance0                          in sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     57 | newInstance                           in     ''
|     45 | newInstance . . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
|    526 | newInstance                           in java.lang.reflect.Constructor
|   1002 | jlrConstructorNewInstance . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     77 | invoke                                in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor
|    102 | callConstructor . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce
|     57 | defaultCallConstructor                in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    182 | callConstructor . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    190 | callConstructor                       in     ''
|    272 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageContentRenderer$PageRenderRequestCreator$1
|     -1 | getSession                            in com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44
|     50 | createSessionIfNecessary . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession
|     43 | getAttribute                          in     ''
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in javax.servlet.http.HttpSession$getAttribute
|     52 | doCall                                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.ServletsGrailsPluginSupport$_enhanceServletApi_closure3
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     57 | invoke                                in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    606 | invoke                                in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     90 | invoke                                in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
|     80 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod
|    271 | invoke                                in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce
|     53 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite
|    116 | call                                  in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    538 | resolveLinkUriToUriAndResource . . .  in org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceTagLib
|     -2 | invoke0                               in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     57 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
```

The GSP is:

```
<%@ page import="com.myDomain.Language; com.myDomain.LandingPromotions" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; "/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>myDomain mailing</title>
    <r:require module="jquery"/>
    <r:layoutResources/>
    <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
        padding: 0;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" align="center" width="700"
       style="border-collapse:collapse; border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center"
                   style="border-collapse:collapse; border:none; width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img class="image_fix" src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'blank.gif', absolute: true)}" alt="" width="253" height="45"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <a href="${createLink(controller: 'landing', action: 'index', absolute: true)}"><img
                                src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'mail-logo2.png', absolute: true)} " alt=""
                                width="131" height="45"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="image_fix" src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'blank.gif', absolute: true)}"
                             alt="" width="254" height="45"/>
                    </td>
<tr>
                    <td colspan="3">


<p>${message(code: 'mail.sendAccountResetMail.greeting', args: [user.firstname, user.surname], locale: user.locale)}</p>

<p><%=message(code: 'mail.sendAccountResetMail.body', args: [password], locale: user.locale)%></p>

<p><%=message(code: 'mail.sendAccountResetMail.footer', locale: user.locale)%></p>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"
        style="background: url(${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'mail-table-bg2.jpg', absolute: true)}) 0 0 no-repeat;">
        <img class="image_fix" src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'blank.gif', absolute: true)}" alt="" width="700"
             height="237"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using an older version of mail plugin? If yes, then upgrade to [new one](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes i am using the latest version of mail plugin mail:1.0.7.

Comment: Stepping through the code it's all fine until it has to load the GSP content. shown above.

 void sendAccountResetMail(MyUser user, String password) {

  mail(
   grailsApplication.config.myDomain.mail.noreply,
   user.email,
   i18nService.message('mail.sendAccountResetMail.title', null, user.locale),
 [view:'/mail/sendAccountResetMail', model:[
     user: user,
     password: password
    ]
   ]
  )
 }